# Neutral wire gauge requirements in relationship to 3 phase gauges

Tags: current

I live in South America, and the electricity is 220V 50 Hz. I am trying to get 3-phase power brought to my farm. It won't be used for 3-phase applications, but rather for different buildings, with 1 phase powering the house, and a 2nd phase powering a building. They will all share the same neutral line.

If each circuit is supplying 20 amps, does the neutral need to be larger? Will it have the current of the 2 phases combined, 40 amps?

Comment: @PatricBright We mainly focus on circuit design questions, there are not many power engineers here and this looks more like a code question, DIY might be better but they mostly focus on residential wiring.

Comment: No, Neutral current does not add up in conventional multi-phase applications. Because the Live wires are out of phase with each other, the Neutral current actually decreases when you combine them together - to the point where a perfectly balanced multi-phase system will have no current at all on the neutral wire.

Comment: Thanks for this.